# Delegate Being Sent To Wrong Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I subclassed my navigation bar, making the title view clickable. When clicked, it will present another view controller. I am creating a protocol in the navigation bar, that will tell the navigation controller that the title view has been clicked. Here is how my navigation bar is defined:

**NavigationBar.h:**

```
@protocol NavigationBarDelegate;

@interface NavigationBar : UINavigationBar
{
    id <NavigationBarDelegate> delegate;
    BOOL _titleClicked;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NavigationBarDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol NavigationBarDelegate
@optional
- (void)titleButtonClicked:(BOOL)titleClicked;
@end
```

The delegate implements one optional method. The `.m` file is as follows:

**NavigationBar.m:**

```
@implementation NavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _titleClicked = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(111/255.f) green:(158/255.f) blue:(54/255.f) alpha:(255/255.f)];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"titlelogo.png"];

    UIButton *titleButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    titleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    [titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(titleButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //        self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    [self.topItem setTitleView:titleButton];

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)titleButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    _titleClicked = !_titleClicked;
    [self.delegate titleButtonClicked:_titleClicked];
}
```

This creates a navbar with a logo and calls the `titleButton` method when the title button has been clicked. Everything is fine up till here and the navigation bar displays nicely.

In my `RootViewController`:

```
NavigationBar *navigationBar = [[NavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
navigationBar.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController setValue:navigationBar forKey:@"navigationBar"];
```

An implementation of `titleButtonClicked` is also there. When I click on the title view however, I get the following error: `-[UINavigationController titleButtonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Why am I getting `titleButtonClicked` sent to `UINavigationController`? Is there something I need to do in my navigation controller? I am just using plain old `UINavigationController`. Do I need to subclass that too? If so, why?

**EDIT:**

Calling `po self.delegate` on line `[self.delegate titleViewClicked:_titleClicked];` in `NavigationBar.m` yields the result below. How did the delegate change its type? How can I fix that?

```
(lldb) po self.delegate
(objc_object *) $1 = 0x07550170 <UINavigationController: 0x7550170>
```

Comment: Try rename delegate property to any other. Seems [self.navigationController setValue:navigationBar forKey:@"navigationBar"]; reassign bar delegate to navController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a clash/ambiguity between your `delegate` and `UINavigationBar`'s `delegate` property. Rename your delegate to disambiguate them.

Comment: So apparently this answer had some down-votes, but no comments to explain them. If you did down-vote this answer, if you have a moment, please would you tell me why? How can I understand how to write better answers if you do not tell me what was wrong with this one?

Comment: If the downvote is still bothering you, it was when you answered, the asker wrote here like 3 comments about your answer. Maybe he down voted because of not understanding your answer. That's when I clarified it, and he deleted the comments.

Answer (score 2):

As @idz said, the problem is with your:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) delegete;
```

<strike>Don't you see that it's weird that you don't even have a:</strike>

```
@synthesize delegete;
```

That's because `UINavigationBar` already defines a `delegate` variable as idz said.

change your declaration to:

```
// use unsafe_unretained in ARC, not assign
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) myDelegete;
```

and of course

```
@synthesize myDelegate;
```

Comment: I do actually have a `@synthesize delegate`. I forgot to paste it in the code above. Isn't it convention to use the name `delegate` for delegates? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: it somewhat is, but if you have many delegates to take care of, you should name each one appropriately different

Comment: (+1) For clarifying my answer and helping out the original poster!

Comment: You typically use `weak` for ARC delegates, not `unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: you use `unsafe_unretained`, because weak is **not** supported in deployment targets earlier than 5.0.