# Objective-C Delegate Type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates

When creating delegates in Objective-C, assume delegate: `id <DelegateName> delegate`, what is the `delegate`'s type supposed to be? So running `po delegete` or `po self.delegate` in LLDB, what is the expected outcome?

If its expected to be `DelegateName`, and it wasn't how would you change it manually?

**EDIT:**

@protocol NavigationBarDelegate
@optional
- (void)titleViewClicked:(BOOL)titleClicked;
@end

`po` output in LLDB:

```
(lldb) po self.delegate
(objc_object *) $1 = 0x073d0840 <UINavigationController: 0x73d0840>
```

As a result, the delegate is being sent to a `UINavigationController` as opposed to the intended class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is `id` so it can be *any* Objective-C object.  The `<DelegateName>` notation means that the object will conform to the `DelegateName` protocol, but that does not affect its type.

Comment: `description` is (also) a member of the `NSObject` *protocol* so if your protocol inherits the `NSObject` protocol it will gain that method as well, and the class is required to implement it.  Also, it is hard (impossible?) to find an obj-c object that doesn't inherit from NSObject, so it will likely always have that method.

Comment: I haven't specified my protocol to inherit anything. Perhaps it inherits by default. In this case, could you please check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775613/delegate-being-sent-to-wrong-class? I've been struggling for a day with that. Thanks

Comment: @Darksky No, your protocol should inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: So why is `po self.delegate` printing out a type?

Comment: @Darksky I didn't know it was; you never posted the output.

Comment: To be slightly more clear, the reason it prints OK is that it is practically impossible that your object (of type `id`) is an objective-c object that doesn't inherit from `NSObject` (where `description` is defined and has its default implementation).  Any object that receives `alloc` is an `NSObject`.  Protocols do not inherit by default, either (it was just noteworthy that `description` was a required method of the `NSObject` protocol, I thought).